# Guessing a number between 1 to 100

Tags: python

The program is supposed to take in an integer from the user and guess what that integer is using binary search.

```
user_num = (int(input("Please think of a number between 0 and 100! ")))
low = 0
high = 100
ans = (high + low)//2

while True:
    print("is your secret number " + str(ans))
    check_ans = input("""enter 'h' to indicate if the guess is too high. 
    enter 'l' to indicate if the guess is too low. 
    enter 'c' if I guessed correctly.""")

      if check_ans == 'h':
        high = ans//2
        ans = high

      elif check_ans == 'l':
        low = ans*2
        ans = low

      elif check_ans == 'c' and check_ans == user_num:
        print("Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(ans))
        break

      else:
        print("I do not understand your command")
```

I believe the issue I am having is occurring in the while loop. I need the program to know when to stop once it reaches the threshold. Say if my integer is 34, once I hit 'h' as input it will drop to 25. Now if I hit 'l' it's going to jump back to being 50.

I guess my question is how do I update the ans variable so the program knows to stay within that range?

Answer (score 1):

Let's go over your conditions. What we want to do is redefine `low` and `high` based on the answer the program received.

```
if check_ans == 'h':
    # We know that ans is lower, so we set our higher bound to slightly below ans
    high = ans - 1

elif check_ans == 'l':
    # We know that ans is higher, so we set our lower bound to slightly above ans
    low = ans + 1
```

Then at the beggining of your loop you want to get `ans` based on the interval by doing `ans = (high + low)//2`.

Overall this gives

```
user_num = (int(input("Please think of a number between 0 and 100! ")))

low = 0
high = 100

while True:
    ans = (high + low)//2

    print("is your secret number " + str(ans))
    check_ans = input("""
    enter 'h' to indicate if the guess is too high. 
    enter 'l' to indicate if the guess is too low. 
    enter 'c' if I guessed correctly.""")

    if check_ans == 'h':
      high = ans - 1

    elif check_ans == 'l':
      low = ans + 1

    elif check_ans == 'c' and check_ans == user_num:
      print("Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(ans))
      break

    else:
      print("I do not understand your command")
```

Comment: I think you have the logic of `h` and `l` backwards. They're saying if the guess was higher or lower than the real answer, not the other way around. If your guess was too high, you should lower the `high` value (to `ans` or maybe better, `ans-1`). If your guess was too low, you should increase `low`.

Comment: You are correct 'h' meaning too high confused me, let me change that

Comment: You have a bug: `lower=ans+1` should be `low=ans+1`.

Comment: Thank you, I should stop trusting myself as being my own IDE

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help. since I was not incrementing the ans variable depending on the decision it was staying the same. Just a follow up questions, why does ans = (high + low) have to be at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: when a user inputs 'c' the algorithm does not recognize the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is slightly wrong when calculating the new interval. Here is the corrected code:

```
user_num = (int(input("Please think of a number between 0 and 100! "))) 
low = 0                                                                 
high = 100                                                              
ans = (high + low) // 2                                                 

while True:                                                             
    print("is your secret number " + str(ans))                          
    check_ans = input("""enter 'h' to indicate if the guess is too high.
    enter 'l' to indicate if the guess is too low.                      
    enter 'c' if I guessed correctly.""")                               

    if check_ans == 'h':
        high = ans
        ans = (high + low) // 2
    elif check_ans == 'l':
        low = ans
        ans = (high + low) // 2
    elif check_ans == 'c' and check_ans == user_num:
        print("Game over. Your secret number was: " + str(ans))
        break
    else:
        print("I do not understand your command")
```

Comment: Please verify that the answer you are giving was not given already. This is almost a copy-paste of the above solution.

Comment: The algorithms are different and the code snippets are similar because we are using the original post as model.

Comment: Another point to take into consideration is that when I start posting, there wasn't no answers yet.

Comment: @AntonioDias. Your answer is okay,  except for a bug in the second elif: it should be `ans == user_num`. (PS: It might be useful if you added some comments to show which lines you changed in the OPs code).

Comment: I found a lot more bugs. :-( The first guess must be the upper limit and not the middle term. Because of that, code will fail if, let's say, the user pick any number greater than the initial middle term.

Comment: @AntonioDias. It may not be optimal, but it does reach the right answer. I tried with both high and low numbers, and it works fine.

Comment: when a user inputs 'c' the algorithm does not recognize the print statement.